# Custom php.ini not loading in server

Tags: php, centos

I tried to install xcache from its source, and I did something wrong and now the php.ini which was being used by loading php in server is not being loaded. What could it be happened? After running "php -v" to check, I got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/modules/apc.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/apc.so: 
undefined symbol: php_rfc1867_callback in Unknown on line 0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This issue can occur when there are multiple versions of PHP installed on your system. Make sure you have only 1 version running

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are loading the correct php.ini

go to your webserver, preferences, make sure to check the path where it loads it from.

Comment: Yes, before trying to install xCache, the php.ini which was loaded is located in /opt/php-5.2.6 and now the php.ini loaded is in /etc/php.ini. I need to make the server load the php located in /opt/php-5.2.6/config/php.ini. How to perform this?